# C Weird incremental behavior with char pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am having a strange behavior with char pointers.  By my knowledge of pointers, I should be able to shift through each pointed character of my char pointer by adding one to it, as a char is one byte.  This does not seem to be the case, however, using the incremental operator +=, ++, and even setting the char pointer equal to itself plus one.  None of these have appeared to affect the pointer as one would think.  If I simply add a number or a variable to my char pointer, it works perfectly as one would expect it.

This does not work:

```
void getNextWord(FILE * pFile)
{
    char * w = (char *)malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    char c;
    while(c != ' ')
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            *(w++) = c;
        }
    }
    *(w++) = '\0';
    printf("%s",w);
}
```

This does work:

```
void getNextWord(FILE * pFile)
{
    char * w = (char *)malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while(c != ' ')
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            *(w + i) = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *(w + i) = '\0';
    printf("%s",w);
}
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: The increment operators are actually doing what you expect. The problem is in your `printf` statement at the end.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, you're incrementing w each time you add a character, so it's always pointing just beyond the last character you've added. When you print it, it's pointing at memory that hasn't been initialized.

```
char *s = w;  // Save a pointer to the beginning of the string.
while (c != ' ') {
  c = fgetc(pFile);
  if (c != ' ') {
    // Store the character at w, then increment w
    // to point at the next available (unused) location.
    *(w++) = c;
  }
}
// Null-terminate the string, and increment w again.
// Now it points one location beyond the end of the string.
*(w++) = '\0';

// This will print whatever happens to be in the uninitialized memory
// at w. It will continue to print until it encounters a null character
// (or "illegal" memory, at which point it will crash).
printf("%s", w);

// This will work as expected because it prints the characters that
// have been read.
printf("%s", s);

// This will also work because it "resets" w
// to the beginning of the string.
w = s;
printf("%s", w);
```

Comment: I understand now.  So if I were to subtract from the char address, then I would be able to properly print it?